# Stereo Camera and Projector Calibration for 3D Scanner

Tags: calibration, scanning

I am trying to understand what is the robust and clean way to calibrate structured light 3d scanner system. I have two cameras placed to be working as stereo and a projector between them.

I found the methods:
 - Just stereo camera calibration
 - 1 camera - 1 projector calibration

What about 2 camera and 1 projector calibration? Which way should be followed for calibration of this total system?

In addition to them I would control the 2 axis arm to rotate object and get complete set of point cloud.